# MongoDB spatial query - error unable to find index or no results

Tags: mongodb, geojson, spatial-query

I am having trouble while executing some spatial queries in MongoDb. I have a collection "cities15000" for which every record has this format

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5624aefe4728347a51b1d751"),
"geonameid" : "292932",
"name" : "Ajman",
"asciiname" : "Ajman",
"latitude" : "25.41111",
"longitude" : "55.43504",
"feature_code" : "PPLA",
"country_code" : "AE",
"population" : "226172",
"elevation" : "",
"timezone" : "Asia/Dubai",
"geography" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "loc" : [ 
        "55.43504", 
        "25.41111"
    ]
}
```

I have created a 2dsphere index `db.cities15000.ensureIndex({loc : '2dsphere'})` and then i tried to get results using `$near` or `$geonear`.

While using $near `db.cities15000.find({loc: {$near: [55.400 ,25.400]} })` i get this error message

> `Unable to execute query: error processing query...n planner returned
>   error: unable to find index for $geoNear query"`

which means that i have a wrong index (i think).

But then when i use `db.runCommand({geoNear: "cities15000",near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 55.400 ,25.400 ] },spherical: true})`
i get:

```
{
"results" : [],
"stats" : {
    "nscanned" : 0,
    "objectsLoaded" : 0,
    "avgDistance" : NaN,
    "maxDistance" : 0.0000000000000000,
    "time" : 0
},
"ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

which means that it doesn't find anything near (false). there are many similar topics but i have tried what is proposed there and nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have an error in index creation and the query:

according to your json schema there is no loc but instead there is 
"geography.loc"

i.e.

```
db.cities15000.find({loc: {$near: [55.400 ,25.400]} })
```

should be something like

```
db.cities15000.find({"geography.loc": {$near: [55.400 ,25.400]} })
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked in my other data set, obviously there was a problem in my json structure as well!